# Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider> when using public lib component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have write a public lib `rd-component`, when I use the public lib component `Goods`, shows error:

```
useReduxContext.js:23 Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
    at pl (useReduxContext.js:23:1)
    at useSelector.js:40:1
    at Vm (Goods.tsx:21:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
pl @ useReduxContext.js:23
(anonymous) @ useSelector.js:40
Vm @ Goods.tsx:21
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
useReduxContext.js:23 Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
    at pl (useReduxContext.js:23:1)
    at useSelector.js:40:1
    at Vm (Goods.tsx:21:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
pl @ useReduxContext.js:23
(anonymous) @ useSelector.js:40
Vm @ Goods.tsx:21
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Vm> component:

    at Vm (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:61481:11)
    at C (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:50109:71)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:35808:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
useReduxContext.js:23 Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
    at pl (useReduxContext.js:23:1)
    at useSelector.js:40:1
    at Vm (Goods.tsx:21:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

this is the `index.ts`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Goods } from 'rd-component';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Goods store={store} appId={'iYDFo0PQQX'} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

this is the store.ts:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './combineReducer';

const logger = createLogger(); 
const initialState = {
   
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [logger, thunk],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    preloadedState: initialState
});

export default store;
```

this is the reducer combineReducer.ts:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { rdRootReducer } from 'rd-component';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    rdRootReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

this is the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-ts-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "rd-component": "0.1.67",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.18.28",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? I have exclude the react redux in the public lib and make it use the react-redux with host app. still facing this error. is it possible to use the public component like this? this is the vite config for public lib:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'node:path';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react({
            
        }),
        dts({
            insertTypesEntry: true,
        })
    ],
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name: 'rd-component',
            formats: ['es','umd'],
            fileName: (format) => `rd-component.${format}.js`
        },
        assetsDir: 'src/assets',
        sourcemap: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components','react-router-dom','react-redux','redux'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                    'styled-components': 'styled',
                }
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
    }
})
```

I have already read these issue:

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1489

this is the react-redux version:

```
> pnpm ls react-redux
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

react-ts-demo@0.1.0 /Users/John/source/frontend/react-ts-demo

dependencies:
react-redux 8.0.5
```